# JS Regex for multiple case types

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a simple way to perform a regex on the following situation but am unsure of how to go about writing one that is efficient.

```
10-20,40,80,1056,20000-65535
```

Or a string like the following:

```
10,20-40,80-1056,20000,60000,65535
```

My regex skills really are not good at the handling of multiple conditions throughout a string and end up lengthy and convoluted like the following:

```
/(\d+){1,6}?((\d+){1,6}\-(\d+){1,6})\,.*/
```

I appreciate any tips on handling patterns like the top two cases (though really it should be able to handle integers in a range 1-65535 and be separated by a comma or a hyphen. Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do, are you trying to match a string of 6 groups of numbers that can contain ranges, or trying to match individual number/ranges appearing in your example strings (it looks like the second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full regex way:

```
var pattern = /^(?:(?:^|[-,])(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-4][0-9]{2}|5(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[0-5])))))+$/;
```

As you can see regex is not an easy way to check if a number is in a range.

Comment: I have added your solution as a reference to a project I am working on, you can see it at https://github.com/jas-/node-libnmap/blob/master/lib/node-libnmap.js#L206

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract those numbers/number ranges from the string, you can do that like this:

```
"10-20,40,80,1056,20000-65535".match(/\d{1,6}(?:-\d+)?/g)
```

That says:

- Match one to six digits...
- ...*optionally* followed by a dash and more digits.
- Globally throughout the string.

Live/explained copy: http://regex101.com/r/aF8cQ0

The above would return this array:

```
["10-20", "40", "80", "1056", "20000-65535"]
```